# Plotting a graph with GD

Tags: php, math, graph, gd

Here it goes.

I have been thinking about this for a long time, and havent really been able to put up a proper way to do it yet. I havent implemented anything yet, as im still designing the thing.

The idea is that i crawl a website for internal links, i got this settled, its easy, but after the crawling, i end up with an array with lots of links, and how many times those particular link appears on the site that i crawled (and how they're connected).

With this huge array, i want to draw a graph somehow. Assuming i can handle the data correctly, the real question here is how i can draw this in a image by the use of the GD library.

I figured if theres less than 12 elements, i can align them up on a unit circle spacing them up as a circle and then connecting them accordingly, so anything up to 12 elements shouldn't be a problem, but if theres more than 12, it could be awesome getting them lined up like this http://nayena.com/stackoverflow/graph.png Or well, thats just a rough drawing, but i guess its just to prove a point.

So i'm here looking for guidance or tips towards getting the math down to getting the stuff lined up in a good way.

I have previously made bar-graphs, so i have little experience doing math with GD. If possible, id prefer not using some plotter-library - in the end, it gives me a better understanding on how things are supposed to be.

Comment: Do you understand the complexity of this problem in the general case? You're sure you want to tackle it yourself instead of just running the matrix through `graphviz` or some other graph-drawing package?

Comment: @JanDragsbaek It seems like your original image link got lost. In case you still have it, could you alter your question to again contain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a whole subfield of CS/IS, with textbooks, research papers and symposia devoted to the subject of graph drawing.

- [GraphDrawing.org](http://www.graphdrawing.org/)
- [Graph Drawing: Algorithms for the Visualization of Graphs](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/0133016153/qid=1089229182/sr=8-1/ref=sr_8_xs_ap_i1_xgl14/103-2475216-1750235?v=glance&s=books&n=507846)
- [Graph Drawing Software (Mathematics and Visualization)](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/3540008810/qid=1089229286/sr=1-3/ref=sr_1_3/103-2475216-1750235?v=glance&s=books)
- [Drawing Graphs: Methods and Models (Lecture Notes in Computer Science)](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/3540420622/qid=1089229286/sr=1-8/ref=sr_1_8/103-2475216-1750235?v=glance&s=books)
- http://vis.computer.org/

You could devote an entire career to how to plot a graph.

Comment: So i might be waaay out of my league here, so i'll stick with graphviz or some other drawing tool, and let the drawing be black magic - thanks for giving a quick heads up on the complexity of the question